Axios call fails in nodejs deployed in AWS lambda
The axios call does not happen in nodejs deployed in aws lambda, subsequent loggers and functionalities fails to execute after axios call
In axios call inside a nodejs function, gets executed sometimes and gets failed the other time, the root cause of it is unknown. The loggers just before axios call gets executed, but anything after that , there is no loggers in cloudwatch.
